# Controlling a digital 360 degree servo

Tags: arduino, rcservo

I have successfully controlled an analog 360 degree servo using a slide potentiometer, with the pot sending a 1000ms signal at one end of the pot and 2000 ms at the other. This gives me nice and smooth rotation speed control all along the pot axis.

I recently got hold of TowerPro MG90D servos, which would be ideal for the app I have in mind because of size and power, but I do not seem to find the right signal to send. If I run the same code, I get the servo turning 100% clockwise first, then in the middle a jittery very small step movement, then at some point full speed counterclockwise.

So my question is, what is the signal I should be sending to the digital servo?

This servo is indeed a 360° servo. Please see https://youtu.be/pyGhbPLZA04

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: At least some sources say this servo has "Normal Servo Travel: 90° (45° each way)".  Not a "360 degree servo".  BTW, most servos (that I have seen) only travel 180 degrees.

Comment: You describe a system with a slide potentiometer, ie able to change a resistance, which generates a change in time period. Although to change the motor speed and direction of rotation you should vary the tension at its ends. Somehow your system description is not complete.

Comment: The thing is, it works fine with an analog 360 degree servo. All I need to hear is, how does one control a digital 360 degree servo.

The potentiometer sends out a value of 0 to 1023, which I convert to a value between 1200 to 1800 respectively. This value is sent to the servo as the length of the control pulse. I would love to find out the way to send control pulses to a digital servo.